# Stretch divider to one side but keep title centered

Tags: html, css

Please run the example below. I'm trying to stretch the left line further to the left to compensate the parent's padding as you can see in the second example, **while** keeping the title centered relative to the parent like in the first example. I can't seem to have both.

(For anyone who's familiar, the divider I'm trying to tweak comes from ant-design)

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 24px;
}

/* Normal use case */

.divider {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 23px;
  height: 1px;
  display: table;
  margin: 16px 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.divider::before, .divider::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
  content: '';
}

.divider-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

/* Trying to stretch the left line to further to the left without puting the title off-center */

.divider.stretched-left {
  left: -24px;
  width: calc(100% + 24px);
  min-width: calc(100% + 24px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="divider">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-left">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would use flexbox instead of table layout then adjust the margin/padding:

<sup>Kept only the relevant code for the demo</sup>

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 24px;
}

/* Normal use case */
.divider {
  display: flex;
  margin: 16px 0;
  align-items:center;
}

.divider::before, .divider::after {
  flex:1;
  height: 1px; 
  background:#AAA;
  content: '';
}
.divider::before {
  margin-right:24px;
}
.divider::after {
  margin-left:24px;
}

.divider.stretched-left:before {
  margin-left:-24px;   
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.divider.stretched-right:after {
  margin-right:-24px;   
  padding-right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="divider">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-left">
    <span class="divider-text">another Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-right">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-right">
    <span class="divider-text">another Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-left stretched-right">
    <span class="divider-text">another Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your original code you can try this:

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 24px;
}

/* Normal use case */

.divider {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 23px;
  height: 1px;
  display: table;
  margin: 16px 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.divider::before, .divider::after {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  content: '';
}


.divider-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

/* Trying to stretch the left line to further to the left without puting the title off-center */

.divider.stretched-left {
  left: -24px;
  width: calc(100% + 48px); /* Updated */
}
/* Added */
.divider.stretched-left:after {
  border-image:linear-gradient(to left,transparent 24px, #aaa 24px) 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="divider">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divider stretched-left">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually thought of this solution. My only concern is that I have to overwrite a lot of styles from the antd design Divider component. At that point I should rewrite the component. Any chance for a solution that keeps the maximum original rules ? Otherwise, I'll mark this as the good answer.

Comment: I thought of flexbox at first too .. but tried to find a solution changing less of the original styles.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It works but I don't understand why. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @Strebler when you remove -24px from the left you will need twice this value added to width to keep the element centred. Doing this will also make the right line to touch the edge that's why I considered a gradient as border image where I will make 24px of transparent ... change the transparent with another color and you will understand the trick

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alright, got it. Thanks, this is the accepted answer. The website tells me to wait a few hours before giving you the bounty.

Comment: @Strebler Why need too much CSS here is solution with minimum CSS Ref this:-  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166867/3947376

Comment: @TemaniAfif By the way, you should really put your second solution, the shortest, as your primary answer. It's what I used in my actual project, it's the one that meets best the requirements (Ant design comes with predef components, so changes should be minimal)

Comment: @Strebler true, but your question is generic and not only focused on ant design. I'd prefer to keep the flexbox solution the first as it will cover more use cases for any future reader.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 24px;
}

.divider {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 23px;
  height: 1px;
  display: table;
  margin: 16px 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%; /* SOLUTION – this is new */
}

.divider::before, .divider::after {
  position: absolute; /* SOLUTION – this has changed */
  top: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 41%; /* SOLUTION – changed, matches desired layout best */
  border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
  content: '';
}

.divider::before{
  left: -24px; /* SOLUTION – compensate #container padding */
  width: calc( 41% + 24px ); /* SOLUTION – add the offset to the width */
}
.divider::after{
  right: 0px; /* SOLUTION */
}

.divider-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="divider">
    <span class="divider-text">Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the logic behind the `41%`. It doesn't work when using another text: https://jsfiddle.net/cj1zspev/

Comment: for sure, but without more information this was the value that best fits. your flexbox solution is more general, I tried to change as little of the given code as possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
.divider.stretched-left {
    left: -24px;
    width: calc(100% + 48px);
    min-width: calc(100% + 48px);
}
```

Just You have to replace last css lines code with above given code.

Comment: Nop, this stretches both sides.

Answer (score -3):

Solution with minimum CSS, without flex, without transform.

```css
.divider {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.divider:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.divider span{
  padding: 0 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
    <span>Title</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: (1) you don't have transparency since you are relying on white background (2) you are not answering the question about stretching one side beyond the parent. padding